# Does anyone know of an Ada plugin for protocol buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers, ada

I'm looking for an Ada plugin for protocol buffers. Looks like there is just about any language plugin available or in the works except for Ada.

Comment: You might want to add links to a couple of the plugins you're talking about, to help people understand the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Here is the link to all of the third parties developing plugins for Protocol Buffers that Google knows of: https://github.com/google/protobuf/wiki/Third-Party-Add-ons

Answer (score 3):

Well, the only thing I found is [this thesis](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:690878/FULLTEXT02.pdf).
Unfortunately, I did not find any source code for a translation tool, i.e. what you name a *plugin*. The only thing I can tell is that the tool was developed in C++.

## UPDATE

There's finally an Ada implementation for Protocol Buffers. It has been developed by Per Sandberg and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/persan/protobuf-ada).

I didn't check if this is a full Ada implementation or if it relies on C/C++ version as a thin binding

Please note that this is an alpha version but usable.

Comment: Yes I found that thesis also. And as you say, he gives the resulting Ada source code that is generated by the protoc "plugin" but he doesn't share the C++ source code that generates the Ada serialize and de-serialize code. I may be using these terms incorrectly, I just started looking into an Ada "plugin" for Protocol Buffers very recently.  I guess I could contact him and ask him if I could get and use his C++ code. Thanks for looking though. You confirm what I have found so far.

Comment: Has there been any progress finding support for using Protocol Buffers in Ada?