# Is there an Ada implementation of Google's protocol buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers, ada

I'm looking for an Ada implementation for protocol buffers. Looks like it's supported in just about any language except for Ada.  I did find a PhD thesis describing development of Ada protocol buffers but I need a product (commercial, freeware, shareware, whatever).

Comment: The official list is [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md) - I don't see any Ada. That doesn't mean it doesn't exist, or that you couldn't write it. Heck, I reimplemented it *again* over the last few days on a new framework *for fun*.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761007/does-anyone-know-of-an-ada-plugin-for-protocol-buffers

Answer (score 1):

There's finally an Ada implementation for Protocol Buffers. It has been developed by Per Sandberg and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/persan/protobuf-ada).

I didn't check if this is a full Ada implementation or if it relies on C/C++ version as a thin binding.

Please note that this is an alpha version but it should be usable.