# Is it possible to define a numeric range for a field in Protocol Buffer?

Tags: types, protocol-buffers, ada

I live in a very safety/critical Ada-ic environment, and have taken the habit of having well defined and bounded type definition. I am also confronted to lots ASN1 usage/evangelists.

One of the key features that some people around me define as superior in ASN1 over protocol buffers is **the ability to define, and therefore check, data range**.

So,

- Is it true that protocol buffers do not have any range definition
  system ?
- Are there any means on top of protocol buffer that could
  provide such a feature ?

Usual numerical types definition such as `int32`, `int64` is out of scope here.

---

**Solutions I've tried / Solution finding process:**
I read this [Google overview](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) and found no reference to any data range definition. Except for features concerning the enum management/representation, and some ordering features.

To give some other references, I heard of/read the links below and became aware of an Ada implementation project.

- [Does anyone know of an Ada plugin for protocol buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761007/does-anyone-know-of-an-ada-plugin-for-protocol-buffers)
- which led to

  - http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:690878/FULLTEXT02.pdf
  - https://github.com/persan/protobuf-ada

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's true that protocol buffers do not have any built-in mechanism for numeric range.

The syntax however does support defining custom options:

```
extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
     optional int32 maxval = 50001;
     optional int32 minval = 50002;
}

message MyMessage {
     required int32 month = 1 [(minval) = 1, (maxval) = 12];
}
```

Depending on library used, these can then either be accessed in runtime using reflection, or you can use a custom code generator to automatically generate verification code.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true that protocol buffers do not have any range definition system ?

Yes

> Are there any means on top of protocol buffer that could provide such a feature ?

You *write code that checks the values are in the expected range*.

Comment: I should have added "other than doing it by hand" :)